# SQL- All possible combination in a Group

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables Product and ProductOwners, I need to find all responsible individuals in the same group. What is a way to write a query to get the desired output

```
Product:
ProductId   Group
1           grp1
2           grp1
3           grp1
4           grp2
5           grp2
6           grp3
7           grp3

ProductOwner:
ProductId     owner
1              x
1              y
2              y
3              z
4              a
4              b
5              b
6              m

Required Output:
ProductId  Responsible
1             x
2             x
3             x
1             y
2             y
3             y
1             z
2             z
3             z
4             a
4             b
5             a
5             b
6             m
7             m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL using just JOIN

```
select distinct pg.ProductId, po.Owner
from Product p
join ProductOwner po on p.ProductId = po.ProductId
join Product pg on p."Group" = pg."Group"
```